# Why does the event listener cause the partials to stop loading?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement the http-auth-interceptor for angularjs, but anywhere I put the event listener $on, the page stops loading.

Here is the plunker of the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/gQvBW2?p=preview

Now, if the directive-auth.js is commented out, then the page will load fine.

I've even tried to put the event listener in the module.run area, but the same result occurs.

Comment: Put your app.js file after everything.  The app.js is what runs the app, so load it last.  Looks like it is working when you do that.

Comment: @TimWithers that fixed it. it seems plunker doesn't make a new hash on change, so unfortunately, the problem doesn't exist for posterity anymore. Can you add an answer anyway so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app.js` file needs to be the last script file loaded.  `app.js` runs the angular app, so any directives, services, etc would not get included, and may throw an error.  In your plunkr, moving the script tag to the bottom fixes the issue.